# Probability of forming a group with different groups of students

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have this question whose solution I don’t really understand.

There are 18 first year, 15 second year, 10 third year and 5 fourth year students in the course TS4332. They are allocated randomly into 4 classes of 12 each. If there are a total of 6 first year and 8 second year students in classes A and B, what is the probability that class D has 4 first year and 4 second year students?

The required probability is given to be $\frac{\binom{12}{4} \binom{7}{4} \binom{5}{4}}{\binom{24}{12}} = 0.032$

I understand that  $\binom{12}{4}$ and  $\binom{7}{4}$ came from the first year and second year to be included in class D, but don’t understand where $\binom{5}{4}$ and $\binom{24}{12}$ came from.

I personally think it’s $\frac{\binom{12}{4} \binom{7}{4} \binom{15}{4}}{\binom{34}{12}}$ instead. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

To make matters simpler, combine the classes $A$ And $B$ into one larger 24 person class.  Further, combine the thirdyear and fourthyear students into one larger group, as we don't really care which is which as it has no relevance to our problem.

Now, supposing that the combined AB class has exactly six first and eight second year students, that only accounts for $14$ of the overall $24$ students that should have been in that combined class.

There are a remaining ten more seats to fill for the class.  Let us fill those seats arbitrarily with students from the combined third/fourth year grade.  It doesn't matter which students they happened to be.

Whichever students those happened to be, this leaves a total of $24$ students left, $12$ of which are first year, $7$ of which are second year, and $5$ of which are third/fourth year.  Whichever students these happened to be, there is an unambiguous way to order them, for example alphabetically, within each of their respective grades and overall.

Recognize then that each of the $\binom{24}{12}$ ways of picking twelve of these remaining students to be in class $D$ are equally likely to occur.

Further, recognize that if we were to have four first year and four second year students in class $D$ that the remaining four seats will be occupied by people from third/fourth year.

Pick which $4$ first year students are assigned to class $D$ from those $12$ remaining first year students.  Pick which $4$ second year students are assigned to class $D$ from those $7$ remaining second year students, and pick which $4$ third/fourth year students are assigned to class $D$ from those $5$ remaining third/fourth year students.

This gives the total number of outcomes for this class (*given the list of all students assigned to classes $A$ and $B$*) as being $\binom{12}{4}\binom{7}{4}\binom{5}{4}$

Taking the ratio gives the probability.

---

Notice: We had to go ahead and assign ten additional third/fourth year students to class A/B after assigning the first and second year students.  This is to ensure the fact that class A/B does not get stuck having to receive additional first or second year students after classes C or D decide to receive all remaining third/fourth year students.  Some of the $\binom{34}{12}$ options you are counting as being supposedly equally likely to occur are impossible outcomes, since according to your logic it was possible to have taken all twelve of the students for class $D$ as third/fourth year, leaving only three third/fourth year students left in total, thereby making it impossible to fulfill the requirement that class A/B not receive any additional first or second year students.

Answer (score 0):

I also obtain that:

- total cases $\binom{33}{14}\binom{15}{10}\binom{24}{12}$
- cases fullfilling the condition $\binom{33}{14}\binom{15}{10}\binom{12}{4}\binom{7}{4}\binom{5}{4} $

and therefore

$$\frac{\binom{12}{4} \binom{7}{4} \binom{5}{4}}{\binom{24}{12}}$$